# Comparing two SQL queries when using IN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause, sql-in

I have two tables, for example the `Employee` and `Project` tables:

```
Employee (id, dept, joining_date)
Project (emp_id, project)
```

With `Project` having foreign key from `Employee` table.
I have to query on `project` and `dept` and return `Employee` in the order of their `joining_date`. Which query will work faster on big data set on the queries below?

```
select * from Employee where id in (select p.emp_id from Project p join Employee e on p.emp_id = e.id where p.project = 'project1' and e.dept = 'dept1') order by joining_date

select * from Employee where id in (select p.emp_id from Project p join Employee e on p.emp_id = e.id where p.project = 'project1' and e.dept = 'dept1') and dept = 'dept1' order by joining_date
```

Or is there any better and simpler way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer query using the `IN()` expression serves no purpose is entirely unnecessary. This will produce the output you need:

```
select e.*
from Project p 
inner join Employee e on p.emp_id = e.id 
where p.project = 'project1' and e.dept = 'dept1'
order by joining_date
```

Comment: Thanks Joel but I am not able to figure out how to make this query in django. The queries I wrote was DJDT printed queries.